# Produce documentation for Python functions

Tags: python, documentation, doxygen

I was wondering if it's possible with Doxygen to generate documentation for Python methods as well. For example, I have a Flask web app that runs solely on functions, all these functions contain docstrings that I want to be generated into a nice format (with Doxygen), however currently I can only get it to do so for classes.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if the answer is no, then sphinx will do this happily with autodoc, so you might want to check it out.

Comment: Look at [this SO-question: Can I document Python code with doxygen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622/can-i-document-python-code-with-doxygen-and-does-it-make-sense)